# Bounded real parts of the solutions of an equation

Tags: complex-numbers

I'd like to show that, with $a,b>0$, the real parts of the solutions $z_n$ of the equation
$$
az+\sqrt{z^2-ib}\tanh\sqrt{z^2-ib}=0
$$
are bounded.

An indication for that can be found if we suppose $\left|z_n\right|\gg b$, the equation is equivalent to
$$
a+\tanh z_n=0
$$
which, assuming $z_n=x_n+iy_n$ with $x_n,y_n$ real,  gives the condition for the real part of the equation
$$
2a+\frac{\sinh 2x_n}{\sinh^2x_n+\cos^2y_n}=0
$$
consequently $x_n<0$. Large positive real parts cannot exist.

Is it possible to find a simple proof for this claim? I thank you in advance for your help.